# Spring JPA Using @Query to return data between two DB2 TIMESTAMP values

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timestamp, db2

I am writing a Springboot JPA REST API that talks to DB2 database and should query a table containing a `TIMESTAMP` field.

Using SQL, the DB2 query to filter rows between two TIMESTAMPs would be like below and it will return 1 record from my test data:

```
SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE SOLD_DATE BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2022-01-01'
```

Since I am using Spring Data JPA, I have defined `CarEntity` which has a `java.sql.Timestamp` field

```
@Entity
public class CarEntity {
   ....
   Timestamp soldDate;
   ...
   //getters and setters
}
```

I am trying to retrieve data like in above SQL query.

To do so, I pass the start and end data in Postman as `Long` values representing start and end date through URL like

```
http://localhost:8080/cars/sold/1420070400/1640995200
```

This endpoint hits my controller method which converts the `Long` into `java.sql.Date` and passes it to repository and in repository, I use `@Query` annotation like below:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, Timestamp>{
    @Query("select c from CarEntity c where c.carModel = 'Toyota' and c.soldDate between :startDate and :endDate") 
    List<CarEntity> getCarsSoldBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

However, this does not work and it returns no data although I know it should return me 1 record.

But if I hardcode the start and end date like below, I get the 1 record:

```
@Query("select c from CarEntity c where c.carModel = 'Toyota' and c.soldDate between '2020-01-01' and '2022-01-01'") 
List<CarEntity> getCarsSoldBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

Of course, problem with that is that I hardcoded startDate and endDate instead of using the ones passed into `getCarsSoldBetween()` method.

**UPDATE-1**

Thanks to @HYUNJUN, I added couple of changes:

1. I use `java.sql.Timestamp` in my Entity like before but my
   Controller, Service, and Repository use `java.util.Date` instead of
   `java.sql.Date` which I was using initially.
2. In my application.properties added below to be able to view what parameters are passed in SQL (NOTE that this introduces significant slowdown, so use only for debugging purposes):
   `logging.level.org.hibernate.sql=DEBUG`
   `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`

Now, when I go to DB2 Bench and issue following query, I will get 2 rows back which is correct:

```
SELECT * FROM MYSCHEMA.CARS WHERE SOLD_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2021-10-04 15:00:00' AND '2021-10-20 00:00:00';

// RETURNS 2 ROWS
```

However, my repository query which looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity, Timestamp>{
    @Query("select c from CarEntity c where c.carModel = 'Toyota' and c.soldDate between :startDate and :endDate") 
    List<CarEntity> getCarsSoldBetween(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

, returns nothing and I would expect to return 2 rows since the start and end date are same as per the logging output:

```
type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Oct 04 15:00:00 PDT 2021]
type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder  binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Wed Oct 20 00:00:00 PDT 2021]
```

So, I am passing the same date range and would expect the same result, but that is not happening

Comment: Try looking at the logs to see what query is actually being run on the database. I suspect it's different from what you want. Add  `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` to the .properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got it working with my CarEntity using `java.sql.Timestamp` as originally posted but that would not filter data correctly and I would keep getting different records from my controller vs records from SQL SELECT.

I figured out that mixing date types like I did above where I used `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` with `java.util.Date` was most likely the cause of this and I suspect date conversion was off causing my controller to return me wrong data.

Then I read this article https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-jpa-date-and-time/ and realized even though my DB2 table uses TIMESTAMP, I can use `java.sql.Date`.

So, I modified my controller, service, repository and entity to use `java.util.Date` instead of using `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`.

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote code almost same with your code above. But i didn't meet issue that you mentioned. I upload my code below. Why don't you compare my code with your code?

```java
package com.springboot.springbootinternals.db2;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Db2Controller {

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    @GetMapping("db2/{start-date}/{end-date}")
    public String db2(
        @PathVariable("start-date") Long startDate,
        @PathVariable("end-date") Long endDate
    ) {

        carRepository.save(Car.builder().date(new Timestamp(1420070401L * 1000)).build());

        Date start = new Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(startDate));
        Date end = new Date(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(endDate));
        List<Car> cars = carRepository.findAll(start, end);
        System.out.println(">>> " + cars);
        return "success";
    }
}

@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Timestamp date;
}

@Repository
interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    @Query("select c from Car c where c.date between :startDate and :endDate")
    List<Car> findAll(Date startDate, Date endDate);
}
```

Additionally, put this option in applicaion.yml for checking correct value is passed to SQL.

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE # show_parameter_value
```

like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but still having problem.  Now my query does not return expected result.  Please see **UPDAE-1** I just added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to retrieve desired results

```
@Repository
public interface CarEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<CarEntity,Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM CarEntity c WHERE c.carModel like %:model% and c.soldDate  > :start and  c.soldDate  < :end ")
    List<CarEntity> getCarsSoldBetween(@Param("model") String model, @Param("start") Date start, @Param("end") Date end);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehdi but I dont think you understand my question